How do unlock "download on demand" files from the OneDrive path after I've disconnected from the account?
I worked for an employer that used OneDrive. When I ceased working for this employer, I wanted to save my OneDrive files, so I copied the contents OneDrive file into another location on my computer.
However, it seems that I didn't ensure that "Make Available Offline" was set. So what I copied were "stubs" of files that Windows would fully retrieve from OneDrive when I tried to open them.
I copied these into my Dropbox path. This has led to a fascinating situation --
If I try to open any of the files, or delete them, or do anything with them, I get an error "The Cloud Provider is not running." This is because, presumably, Windows doesn't understand that folder to be connected to a OneDrive account anymore, and all it has are a bunch of "file stubs" in it.
This has caused Dropbox to stop syncing. It's "stuck" on this folder. It can't access the files (just like I can't), so it has ground to a halt.
I cannot delete the files. I can't move them. I can't open them. I can't do anything with them, because I'm assuming Windows wants to download them from OneDrive, but is no longer connected to that account.
I have tried to turn off "Files On Demand" in OneDrive, but that doesn't work (I'm not connected to that account anymore, remember, so it can't fully download them).
What complicates this a little is that I'm still running OneDrive (for my new employer), it's just connected to a different account. I have both reset OneDrive (from the command line) and forcibly quit OneDrive (from Task Manager). Neither has affected my problem.
I have tried telling Dropbox to make the folder "online only" (to try and get it to stop syncing it), but it's still stuck, because I'm guessing it has changes queued that it needs to reconcile.
I don't think I can correct this via OneDrive. Since I'm not connected to that account anymore, I guess there's nothing OneDrive can do to "resolve" the files.
Can I tell the Windows file-system in general to stop trying to get them from the cloud and just let me delete them?
Can I somehow get Dropbox to forget about the folder (and all the queued changes)?

OneDrive placeholders are implemented as a type of reparse point, with metadata attached to files telling the OS to allow a specific driver to intercept the file operations.
Run fsutil reparsePoint delete on each of them to strip the metadata and turn them into regular empty files.
Dropbox "Smart Sync" placeholders are also reparse points, but a different type handled by a different driver (custom to Dropbox rather than using the Windows built-in cloud support). Common symlinks, junctions, and drive mountpoints are also implemented as different kinds of reparse points.

Error:  Access to the cloud file is denied.
